# Data isn't sending from AndroidStudio to phpMyAdmin / 000webhost

Tags: php, sql, web-hosting

---

I'm trying to create a basic Register and Log in Application by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQXfIidfFMo&t=193s and because the code in Android Studio has shown 0 Compile Errors I've decided not to put that here.

### What's wrong

Many users have reported in the comments section both old and new that they could not get their information sent to their database so any help would be greatly appreciated.  The user inputs their 'name', 'username', 'password', and 'age' to register and this information is to then sent to my database hosted on 000webhost. Everything has been followed to the T.

The name of the table is called 'user'.

Here is the code to my Login.php file

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","id7390457_user","abcd1234","id7390457_data");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $age, $username, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Here is the code to my Register.php file

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id7390457_user", "abcd1234", "id7390457_data");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

I have been under the impression that the line

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id7390457_user", "abcd1234", "id7390457_data");
```

Is followed by using ('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'nameofdatabase')

However as I am doing this from my Mac so my host is 'localhost'
My DB Name is: id7390457_data
My DB User is: id7390457_user

I've tried using 'localhost:3306'
I've tried just 'user' and 'data'
I've watched YouTube videos, visited websites in other languages and none have seemed to provide any advise.

I've deleted multiple databases starting from scratch but I still face the issue whereby my information isn't being sent to phpMyAdmin on 000webhost.
My webhost doesn't have an index.html page but I don't think that this would be the issue.

#### Thank you

Any help would mean the world to me. Thank you wish you well!

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` said what?

Comment: don't store plain text passwords, you *will* have your db compromised. Use `password_hash()/password_verify()`.

Comment: are you using their **FREE** hosting service? are you reading these comments and the answer below?

Comment: Also use php's error reporting and error handling on the connection. You'll see what's (not) going on.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I don't think 000webhost provides error reporting/handling. Yes I am using FREE hosting service. I think it may have to do with me actually calling my 'Register.php' file. I don't have an index page to provide a direct link to the php file do you think that matters?

Comment: you can't connect on localhost through their free service, you need to pay for it. Consider this an "answer".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just got a successful connection with error lines.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

You are right, the `mysqli_connect` expects the host, user, pass and db name in that order, so if the database is running and the values are correct as you said, this looks OK.

However on this line, note the second argument `ssis`:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $age, $username, $password);
```

It states the type of the parameters, `s` for string and `i` for integer. It looks like the order is messed up, because `age` is expected as a string and `username` as an integer. If you replace it with `siss`, I would expect it to work.

More info: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: although most likely the issue, I feel that this might even go deeper. I am pretty sure they're not even able to get a result set back, yet alone a connection. I'd read the question again and look at their web host. I know that one all too well.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for your reply! I have tried changing this before to match the order but it did not work. I think maybe it has to do with me actually calling the 'Register.php' file from Android Studio. I may need an index page to call it directly?